# how can I send json instead of form-data to my symfony controller

Tags: web-services, json, rest, symfony1, symfony-1.4

there a tons of tutorials on the web about how to set the action-response to type json in a symfony controller. But how can I receive JSON?

$request->getRequestFormat() returns "json", but the json data seems to be lost, because $request->getParameter() doesn't work.

This is my routing:

```
importservice:
  url: /importservice
  class: sfRequestRoute
  param: { module: remoteaccess, action: import, sf_format: json }
  requirements:
    sf_method: post
    sf_format: json
```

Edit:

getParameter() decodes multipart/form-data (html-forms) and get-parameters, so I thought it also does this for content-type application/json.
I need this for a web-service which posts data. My basic idea was that it makes no difference whether a human fills out html-forms or a bot sends the data directly. I thought that encoding the content to json is easier to implement than encoding it to multipart/form-data.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: Why do you need to send data in JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came to this conclusion:

Symfony's getParameter() method provides GET-parameters (url) and parameters which are defined in the routing (uri). The items of multipart data will also be provided, because this media-type is just a container for sub-content packages, whereas application/json is already the content itself. In other words: multipart just declares that there is more than one content-package.

One might claim that json is also a data-container, but I think that multipart contains data on the "http-level", whereas json contains data on the "content-level".

The confusion arises by the fact that multipart is actually something like a meta-media-type.